# How I can avoid rerendering of all React pure components when only one field in state changed?

Tags: reactjs

I am using `Reactstrap` and custom `React.PureComponent` that consist of combined `Reactstrap` components. Also I use top React component to store all application state and pass data, necessary for `render()` function, through props.

```
...
<Container>
    <AppTabs
        main_tab={
            <MainTab
                general_change={this.general_change}
                submit_form={this.submit_form}
                ... other props

                group_widget={<GroupWidget
                    general_change={this.general_change}
                    groups={this.state.groups}
                    group_select_hndl={this.group_select_hndl}
                />}

                bootstrap_action={<BootstrapAction
                    general_change={this.general_change}
                    available_actions={this.state.available_actions}
                    bootstrap_action={this.state.bootstrap_action}
                />}
            />
        }
        mac_tab={
            <MacTab
                general_change={this.general_change}
                submit_form_macs={this.submit_form_macs}
                save_mac_status={this.state.save_mac_status}
            />
        }

        group_change_hndl={this.group_change_hndl}
        general_change={this.general_change}
    >
    </AppTabs>
</Container>
...
```

This is code of the `general_change()` function

```
general_change(event) {
    let state_id = event.target.name;
    let update_state = {};
    update_state[state_id] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(update_state);
}
```

I use it to save data that user put in input fields.

In theory `PureComponent` should not be rerendered if props does not changed. But in my case any keystroke in input field or when user click on radiobutton trigger rerender. I seeing it using React browser extension. I wonder why this happening? Because selection of different radiobutton change value of only one field in state variable. And only one component will receive new value through props. All the rest components receive the same values.

To limit unnecessary rerenders I probably can use `shouldComponentUpdate()`. But why PureComponent not working in my case?

Comment: the component will also re-render if state changes. if you're changing state with `this.setState({...})` then of course your component should re-render otherwise how else dose your app know what a user just typed or selected?

Comment: @JoeLloyd I thought that if state not belongs to component then it not track it changes. I mean in my case state only exists in top component. All child component uses only props.
So I should use `shouldComponentUpdate()` and there are no exists other ways to avoid rerender?